# How to distribute .bar files through my website?

Tags: web, blackberry-10

Is it possible to provide distribution of bar files like in previous versions?

**Example:**

I distributed cod files within my webpage/website by clicking on single link to download. How can i distribute the application in similar way (without contacting blackberry app world)

I cant find the respective mime type for distribution and I can not find any relevant links to distribute the bar files. I have gone through this [link](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.quickstart/topic/sign_and_publish_your_app.html), but it deals with the app world.

Is there a way to distribute the bar file to my client without submitting my app to blackberry app world?

Comment: So what's happening currently?  It's opening/running instead of downloading when you put a link to it?

Answer (score 3):

If you provide a singed BAR file to customers or beta testers they can 'side load' the BAR file to their devices using either the official development tool sets from BlackBerry, or one of a number of utilities developed by the side loading community. The devices have to be placed in developmer mode to install the BAR, but if the BAR is fully signed they can be taken out of developer mode afterwards.

There is no equivalent to downloading a JAD/COD file set from BBOS